# Volumetric slice plot of a parallelepiped volume data

Tags: python, numpy, sage

I have a parallelepiped volume data defined by three vector:

a     2.468000    0.000000    0.000000

b    -1.234000    2.137351    0.000000

c     0.000000    0.000000   32.000000

my grid is described by 40 40 500 points, respectively for the axes a,b,c. As you can see the three vectors are not mutually orthogonal and this causes a lot of problems for the reading of the grid.

My original plan was to read my raw data and then to extract several volumetric slices to be processed with sagemath to produce super nice pictures. Regrettably I looked in the python documentation for something like that and I found several command that can be used for an orthogonal volume (ndgrid, easyviz.slice_) but none for not-mutually orthogonal volume data.

In the Scitools package and numpy I found the following command

[Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/) provides:

- mgrid
- ogrid
- meshgrid

[Scitools](http://scitools.googlecode.com/hg/doc/api/html/index.html) provides:

- ndgrid
- boxgrid

then I was looking also among the `matplotlib` functions but they are so many that I simply gave up.

Is there some friendly programmer that can put me in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are you after?

You can easily create an array of shape `(40, 40, 500, 3)` where the item at position `[a, b, c]` is a 3 element array holding the x, y, z coordinates of the corresponding parallelepiped grid point as follows:

```
a = np.array([2.468000, 0.000000, 0.000000]).reshape(1, 1, 1, 3)
b = np.array([-1.234000, 2.137351, 0.000000]).reshape(1, 1, 1, 3)
c = np.array([0.000000, 0.000000, 32.000000]).reshape(1, 1, 1, 3)
A = np.linspace(0, 1, num=40).reshape(40, 1, 1, 1)
B = np.linspace(0, 1, num=40).reshape(1, 40, 1, 1)
C = np.linspace(0, 1, num=500).reshape(1, 1, 500, 1)
grid = a * A + b * B + c * C
```

Comment: Dear Jaime, thank you for your help, this is exactly the first part of what I need. With this, I have the points of the grid, now I have to associate at each point a float value (the density) that I read from a text file. After that, I should select a plane in that volume (maybe interpolating the density values of the grid) and plot in 2D the resulting colored(?) image, with isovalue curves. That's all. thanks a lot for your help, I love python but I'm still a newbie.